# Django REST Framework how to add context to a ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The ViewSets do everything that I want, but I am finding that if I want to pass extra context to a template (with TemplateHTMLRenderer) then I will have to get at the functions that give responses.. (like list(), create(), etc)

The only way I can see to get into these is to completely redefine them in my ViewSet, but it seems that there should be an easy way to add a bit of context to the Template without having to redefine a whole set of methods...

```
class LanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Viewset for Language objects, use the proper HTTP methods to modify them"""
    # TODO: add permissions for this view?
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('name', 'active')
```

Right now my code is looking like this but I will be wanting to add different context to the responses and I am trying to avoid redefining an entire method for such a small change. like this...

```
class LanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Viewset for Language objects, use the proper HTTP methods to modify them"""
    # TODO: add permissions for this view?
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('name', 'active')

    def list(self, **kwargs):
        """Redefinition of list"""

        ..blah blah everything that list does
        return Response({"foo": "bar"}, template_name="index.html")
```

Comment: you're doing it wrong, there are no (should not be) templates in a DRF API. context is passed to the serializer, and then the serializer data goes to a render that checks the `Accept` header on the request to define how to render the data: json, csv, and even HTML

Comment: so from what I gather, the API should just be taking data and processing it how DRF is made to do.. I should then use another app with views and forms, etc to send data to the API to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: follow the whole tutorial http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: @pleasedontbelong I have done that tutorial and the long form tutorial as well as read through most of the docs. I am still no closer to an answer to my question though. If there was not supposed to be a template in DRF then why did they include a `TemplateHTMLRenderer` and a way to pass it extra context in responses? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/

Comment: @pleasedontbelong the tutorial does a great job at introducing how DRF works, but in my opinion it does not do such a great job of showing how to implement these API's in the wild. Like I asked a few comments ago...Should I be using the api views as the ones that render forms in templates? Or is it better to just let the api do its thing and use other separate apps to create views and render forms in them that only submit to the API URL's?

Comment: the renderer just takes the data and displays it in one specific format. DRF has a `TemplateHTMLRenderer` so you could display the data in a HTML format,, you can't pass extra data to the context because the same data should be available to all enabled renders, so that "extra data" should be available in the serializer. IMHO an API is for programs only, so no forms or human friendly interfaces should be available, I'd create a second app for humans :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. That was my original thinking but someone else led me down this path. Good to have ot clarified, i will take care of it in other apps

Comment: I beg to differ. The job of a ViewSet is to return native python data types. It is then the job of the renderer to render that into whatever way is required. JSON or HTML.There are tons of cases where REST API's need to return data in HTML templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I disagree with 'pleasedontbelong' in principle, I agree with him on the fact that the extra contextual data ought to be emitted from the serializer. That seems to be the cleanest way since the serializer would be returning a native python data type which all renderers would know how to render.

Heres how it would look like:

ViewSet:

```
class LanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('name', 'active')

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context['foo'] = 'bar'
        return context
```

Serializer:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field = serializers.CharField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        # Access self.context here to add contextual data into ret
        ret['foo'] = self.context['foo']
        return ret
```

Now, foo should be available inside your template.

Another way to achieve this, in case you don't wish to mess with your serializers, would be to create a custom TemplateHTMLRenderer.

```
class TemplateHTMLRendererWithContext(TemplateHTMLRenderer):
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        # We can't really call super in this case, since we need to modify the inner working a bit
        renderer_context = renderer_context or {}
        view = renderer_context.pop('view')
        request = renderer_context.pop('request')
        response = renderer_context.pop('response')
        view_kwargs = renderer_context.pop('kwargs')
        view_args = renderer_context.pop('args')

        if response.exception:
            template = self.get_exception_template(response)
        else:
            template_names = self.get_template_names(response, view)
            template = self.resolve_template(template_names)

        context = self.resolve_context(data, request, response, render_context)
        return template_render(template, context, request=request)

    def resolve_context(self, data, request, response, render_context):
        if response.exception:
            data['status_code'] = response.status_code
        data.update(render_context)
        return data
```

To add data into the context, ViewSets provide a `get_renderer_context` method.

```
class LanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('name', 'active')

    def get_renderer_context(self):
        context = super().get_renderer_context()
        context['foo'] = 'bar'
        return context
```

`{'foo': 'bar'}` should now be available in your template.

Comment: I use a subclass of `AdminRenderer` instead of `TemplateHtmlRenderer`, where I had similar success overriding `get_context`, which is called by `AdminRenderer`'s `render` method.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue and resolved in a slightly different way in Django Rest Framework (DRF) 3.x. I believe it is not necessary to override the relatively complex render method on the `TemplateHTMLRenderer` class, but only the much simpler method `get_template_context` (or: `resolve_context` in earlier versions of DRF).

The procedure is as follows:

1. Override the `get_renderer_context` method on your ViewSet (as already suggested):

   ```
   def get_renderer_context(self):
       context = super().get_renderer_context()
       context['foo'] = 'bar'
       return context
   ```
2. Subclass `TemplateHTMLRenderer`, but only override the `get_template_context` method instead of the entire render method (render calls `self.get_template_context` to retrieve the final context to pass to the template):

   ```
   class ModifiedTemplateHTMLRenderer(TemplateHTMLRenderer):

       def get_template_context(self, data, renderer_context):

       """
       Override of TemplateHTMLRenderer class method to display
       extra context in the template, which is otherwise omitted.
       """

       response = renderer_context['response']
       if response.exception:
           data['status_code'] = response.status_code
           return data
       else:
           context = data

           # pop keys which we do not need in the template
           keys_to_delete = ['request', 'response', 'args', 'kwargs']
           for item in keys_to_delete:
               renderer_context.pop(item)

           for key, value in renderer_context.items():
               if key not in context:
                   context[key] = value
           return context
   ```

`{{ foo }}` is now available as a template variable - as are all other variables added in `get_renderer_context`.