# Django Rest Framework ViewSets: Include arbitrary context content in Response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How does one initialize the Response() with additional arbitrary content across all ViewSet methods, without overriding each method individually?

Use Case:  I would like to include arbitrary content (in this case a Form object along with the serialized results in a Rest Framework ViewSet Response.

I know that if I override an individual ViewSet method (such as list) this is easy enough:

```
def list():
    serializer = FooSerializer()
    context = {
      'form': BarForm(), 
      'data': serializer.data
      }
    return Response(context)
```

I also know that I can populate the serializer with additional context using the get_serializer_context() method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038742/pass-request-context-to-serializer-from-viewset-in-django-rest-framework)

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def get_serialzier_context(self):
        context = {'form': BarForm()}
        return context
```

And that does indeed get passed to the serializer

I also know that I can override the to_representation() method on the Serializer class, and use my arbitrary context to further manipulate serialized data at the instance level, but that's not what I want.

I have also explored the use of the get_renderer_context() method [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202380/django-rest-framework-how-to-add-context-to-a-viewset), but that hasn't borne fruit yet.

I have even looked to the rest_framework/pagination.py code, as it injects 'previous', 'next', and 'count' attributes into the context:

```
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', data)
        ]))
```

And the above provides a pretty good clue about creating a Response instance with passed values - which is exactly what I did in the first example, in the ViewSet's list() method.

So I guess the question best comes down to something along the lines of

> How does one initialize the Response() with this arbitrary content
>   across all ViewSet methods, without over-riding each method
>   individually?